# What is a shortest expression of a conditional statement in vbscript?

Tags: syntax, vbscript, styles

For example, if I have the following code:

```
dim a
if a = 0 then
    b = 1
else
    b = 2
end if
```

Can I shorten this code without sacrificing its validity? Thanks.

Comment: Anyone thought of this:
b = (a = 0) * 1 + (a <> 0) * 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK , there is no way to shorten this code directly, but there you can do as :

```
dim a,b : a =0 : b=1  ''set a = 0 & b = 1 directly 
'' Now as per your requirement 'a' value might change in script flow then you can set value    as 
If a > 0 then  b= 2
```

Hope this help.........

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [single-line syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9%28VS.84%29.aspx) for the `If...Then...Else` statement:

```
If a = 0 Then b = 1 Else b = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, you could write a helper function to mimic the VBA [IIf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264412.aspx) function:

```
Function IIf(expr, truepart, falsepart)
    If expr Then
        IIf = truepart
    Else
        IIf = falsepart
    End If
End Function

b = IIf(a=0, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic If block is the simplest conditional statement in VBScript.  VBScript does not have support for a [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).